# Firebase init error: Unable to authorize access to project [PROJECT ID]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to initialize firebase functions for an iPhone app.

I have two separate accounts that I have different firebase projects on.

I ran firebase init, but I get an error

> Error: Unable to authorize access to project[PROJECT ID]

where the project ID is a project id for a project in the account im not using.

I used

> Firebase use --add

and it worked perfectly.

I ran

> Firebase list

and the project I want to init is listed there. But when I ran the init again I got the same error with the wrong project ID still.

ps. the other project ID doesn't come up in Firebase list

EDIT: I logged out of the different account and am logged into the correct account.

Comment: You could try this one.
[Http Error: 401](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45590689/4362756)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the alias. Aren't you just setting your project for staging?
After Firebase use --add, you should do like

```
What alias do you want to use for this project? (e.g. staging) default
```

and also

```
What alias do you want to use for this project? (e.g. staging) dev
```

In other words, you have to switch all the alias to the project you re trying to use.

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

`Firebase login` to the account that has the project.

Comment: I'm in the account that has the project

Answer (score 0):

If you're switching between two Google accounts, you have to `firebase logout` from one and `firebase login` to the other before you can access the projects in those different accounts.

Comment: Yes, I did that